# Show sheet for new document window

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

When the user creates a new document in my `NSDocument`-based Cocoa application, I want the new document window to show a sheet where the user can set some initial document parameters.

This sheet shall not be displayed, however, when an existing document is loaded via File > Open.

Is there any existing mechanism which I can hook into for implementing this? Or any recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jay correctly stated in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671472/762322) that, in order to determine whether an instance of the `NSDocument` subclass represents a new document rather than a loaded from a file one,  `initWithType:error:` has to be overridden, which only gets called for new documents. But starting the sheet in there won't work, unfortunately, as the window has not yet been created at the point `initWithType:error:` is called.

The missing link to get this working is to instead set an instance variable named e.g. `newDocument` to `YES` in `initWithType:error:`. The actual call to `[NSApp beginSheet:…]`, then, has to be made in `windowDidBecomeKey:`. Also, the `newDocument` variable should be set to `NO` there, in order to prevent the sheet from reappearing each time the window becomes key again.

Comment: Good answer; this works very well for me. :)  ... in some cases one might want to check if the document settings exists and then pop up the sheet, even for loaded documents (but only once, of course)

Answer (score 3):

Override `initWithType:error:` in your `NSDocument` subclass.
From the documentation (see [NSDocument Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsdocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

*You can override this method to perform initialization that must be done when creating new documents but should not be done when opening existing documents.*

Comment: Thanks! Where do I put the call to my sheet's `beginSheet...` method? If I put it in `initWithType:error:`, the sheet gets displayed in a window of its own, not attached to the document window as a sheet.